# EF Core expression tree FORMAT equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

I'm trying to build dynamic SQL queries using expression trees. I'm having issues implementing SQL Function `FORMAT` on datetime datatype. I would like to generate expression that would translate to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM ComputerUpdate 
WHERE FORMAT(UpdatePerformed, 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh-mm-ss') LIKE '%15/12/%'
```

I was able to dynamically generate `LIKE` part of SQL query, but I cannot find `FORMAT` equivalent.

I tried the following code:

```
var format_method = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new[] { typeof(string) });

return Expression.Call(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, prop.Name),
    format_method,
    Expression.Constant("dd/MM/yyyy, hh-mm-ss", typeof(string))
);
```

However, this approach throws the following exception:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(o => o.UpdatePerformed.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy, hh-mm-ss").Contains("15/12/")' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ToString' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Another downside of this approach is that it does not work on nullable DateTime properties - in that case, the following exception was thrown:

> Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' declared on type 'System.DateTime' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'

I am using EF Core 7.0

Comment: Before trying, I would suggest you read this https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: You are trying to filter dates by year? Then you are doing that wrong. Database indexes ignored completely.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts thank you for your advice. I completely forgot that `CONVERT` function in SQL can also perform datetime formatting. But then my question would be what would be expression tree equivalent of CONVERT function that accepts 3 parameters (ie. `CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), ComputerUpdate, 28)`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the idea behind that qouery would be that user can perform search for parts contained in that datetime column (ie. 12/12 would, theoretically, match 12/12/2022, 09/12/1209, ...) - so filtering would not be performed just on year or month or date

Comment: Well, then you have to create [function mapped in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) and inject call to this function in Expression Tree.

Comment: If you want to filter on dates, I would suggest you use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), and join with that an perform the filtering on the calendar table.

Comment: It is a good idea to test what you want with a literal query before trying to build an `Expression` tree. That way you would find out that there is no `ToString(string fmt)` that is translated by EF Core into SQL - you will need to manually construct the expression using the components. See the list of understood [Database Functions for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#date-and-time-functions), assuming that is your provider. LINQPad is a good tool for experimenting.

Comment: @NetMage is there maybe a way to call existing SQL function using expression trees? I would like to call `CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), [datetimecolumn], 29)` (which is existing, SQL server defined function, since `Convert.ToString(DateTime, IFormatProvider?)` cannot be translated to SQL query.

Comment: EF Core has provision for creating manual mapping to user defined functions or custom SQL as discussed [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping) as mentioned earlier by @svy.